# Generalization of Watson's triple product

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

In [Watson's thesis](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.0425v3.pdf%29) (page 51) we can find his beautiful triple product formula. My question is that does there exist a generalization of this formula? By generalization, I mean:

If $\phi_n$'s are orthonormal Hecke-Maass eigenforms in some arithmetic congruence (compact/noncompact) manifold $M=\Gamma\backslash G$, i.e. normalized eigenforms of Laplacian and Hecke operators  in corresponding manifold, then for $I\subset\mathbb{N}$,
$$\left(\int_M\prod_{n\in I}\phi_ndvol_M\right)^2=C\frac{L\left(\frac12,\bigotimes\limits_{n\in I}\phi_n\right)}{\prod\limits_{n\in I}L(1,sym^2\phi_n)},$$ for some constant $C$.

$\textbf{Question}:$

1) Is the above (or some modified version) true?

2) If not, why is this only true for THREE eigenforms?

Thanks. Any help or reference is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason it works for three (but not other numbers) is the uniqueness of trilinear functionals.  Let $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(F)$, $F$ a local field and let $\pi_i$ ($1\leq i\leq 3$) be three irreducible admissible representations.  Then there is at most one $G$-invariant functional on $\pi_1 \otimes \pi_2 \otimes \pi_3$ (this is mostly due to D. Prasad).  Now let $\pi_i$ instead be global automorphic representations, and $G$ the adelic group. Then one such functional is given by the integral on the LHS of Watson's formula, so by the uniqueness it must factor as a product of local functionals, and this "explains" why the integral is Eulerian.

For the general question of when one should expect such integral representations for L-functions see the papers of [Sakellaridis](http://math.newark.rutgers.edu/~sakellar/rs.pdf) and [Sakellaridis–Venkatesh](http://math.newark.rutgers.edu/~sakellar/harmonic-submission.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much Professor Lior. Can you kindly specify which result of Sakellaridis-Venkatesh you are referring to, as I am being unable to find it?

Comment: References added.